# Saber se uma classe é nativa do JAVA ou criada pelo Usuário?

Tags: java, reflexão

Criei um método que usa reflection para executar os getters em cima de um objeto, porém preciso saber se a classe é nativa do JAVA, por exemplo: **java.lang.String**, ou se foi implementada pelo usuário: **br.com.foo.bar**.

No PHP eu consigo saber se foi o Usuário que definiu a classe utilizando o seguinte:

> $ReflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($nome_da_classe);
>
> $ReflectionClass->isUserDefined();

Teria alguma forma de eu conseguir isso em JAVA sem fazer um monte de:

```
method.getReturnType() == String.class || method.getReturnType() == Integer.class
```

Comment: No java você tem o `getClass()` do objeto, que lhe retornará a classe. Para comparar você usa o método `equals()` também do objeto.

Comment: @Dener exatamente isto que não quero fazer, pegar a classe e ficar comparando com todas as nativas do java.

Comment: Ah sim agora entendi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/** Testa se o pacote da classe começa com "java." ou "javax."
  * Talvez seja o caso de também testar os pacotes "org." listados em:
  * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-summary.html */
private boolean ehClasseDoJava(Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz.getPackage() != null
        && clazz.getPackage().length() >= 6
        && (clazz.getPackage().substring(0, 5).equals("java.")
            || clazz.getPackage().substring(0, 6).equals("javax."));
}
```

Use assim:

```
System.out.println(ehClasseDoJava(seuObjeto.getClass())); // imprime true ou false
```

Comment: Bem pensado está forma de pegar o package e ver de onde vem. Amanhã testo se tudo deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente as classes carregas pelo ClassLoader do sistema(bootstrap) retornam null quando chamamos o seu ClassLoader.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Main.class.getClassLoader()); //retorna o Classloader
    System.out.println(System.class.getClassLoader()); //retorna null
    System.out.println(Sdp.class.getClassLoader()); //retorna null
    System.out.println(BufferSecrets.class.getClassLoader()); //retorna null
    System.out.println(AbsoluteIterator.class.getClassLoader()); //retorna null
  }
```

}

esse pode ser uma alternativa para verificar se a classe foi carregada pelo bootstrap, caso seja, então a classe é primitiva da JVM.

Comment: Pode ser uma forma boa e também eficiente de se descobrir, mas é preciso ficar atento se o `getClassLoader()` da implementação do Java usada tem esse comportamento de retornar `null` mesmo, como avisa a documentação do método.

Comment: Na própria documentação deixa claro que existe a possibilidade de  não retornar null.

É um risco!